# i want to use PHP session value in JSON page

Tags: php, json

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Calendar").eventCalendar({
        eventsjson: 'event.default.json.php',
        jsonDateFormat: 'human'
    });
});
```

While loading the page,I am calling event calendar.in this file  event.default.json.php  am fetching the values from database and returning the values using JSON_ENCODE.Now i want to fetch the data based
on PHP session value. 
Can anyone tell How to pass the session value to event.default.json.php page.

```
**event.default.json.php**
    header('Content-type: text/json');
    class Json{
        public function getApp(){
            $sql=mysql_query('select * from p,a WHERE p.id=a.customer_id');
            $i=0;
            while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql,MYSQL_ASSOC)){ 
                $json[$i]['description'] = $row['fname']."'s Appointmet" ;
                $i++;
            } 
            echo json_encode($json);
            echo json_encode($_SESSION[name]);  
        }}
    $event = new Json;
    $event->getApp();
```

Comment: event.default.json.php should have access to the session like any other PHP file.

Comment: you should post code from event.default.json.php

Comment: No i am not able to access the session values in event.default.json.php page......

Comment: @JamesTaylor I am not getting u...

Comment: Show us *how* you're trying to access the session data.

Comment: Put that code into your question please. It's unreadable in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

did start the session using

`session_start()`

?

You need to put more code here otherwise it's difficult to help

Comment: In the header page i have already initiated the session using session_start()

Comment: @user But did you initiate it in `event.default.json.php`? You have to call `session_start()` in every request you want to use a session. AJAX requests are separate requests.

Comment: I have tried with that possibility...its showing error when i am using session in my JSON page....

Comment: error getting json: plugin/calendar/json/event.default.json.php

Comment: what you need to show us is the php error not the js error because your first probleme was that you could not use session in the php file aint it ?